# WCF get data from client

Tags: wcf

I'm new in wcf.
I am server and want to give 'ID' parameter, and get string type data from my client fro that ID.
Can anybody help me, how I can organize it, or where to look some samples ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the getting started tutorial on WCF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx
Feel free to post a more specific question after you gone through the basics of creating and consuming a WCF service. Good luck!